# Where are Swift's constants in Kotlin Multiplatform?

Tags: swift, kotlin, kotlin-multiplatform

I'm trying to create a number formatter in Swift from Kotlin code in a KMP project. The code looks like this:

```kotlin
    val formatter = NSNumberFormatter().apply {
        locale = NSLocale("US")
        maximumFractionDigits = 2u
        roundingMode = NSNumberFormatterRoundingMode.down
    }
```

Unfortunately, the last line setting the rounding mode does not work because I invented the `down` constant. The `roundingMode` property is of type `platform.Foundation.NSNumberFormatterRoundingMode`, which is an alias for `platform.darwin.NSUInteger`, which is an alias for `kotlin.ULong`. All of this is fine, but, where are the constants I can assign as `roundingMode`?

The equivalent line in swift would look like:

```swift
        formatter.roundingMode = .down
```

And if I reveal the code for `.down` I get to see the following:

```swift
    public enum RoundingMode : UInt, @unchecked Sendable {

        
        case ceiling = 0

        case floor = 1

        case down = 2

        case up = 3

        case halfEven = 4

        case halfDown = 5

        case halfUp = 6
    }
```

I guess I can write directly the constant `2` myself in Kotlin code, but is there a better way to replicate these enums/integer values so that the source code is a bit more readable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The constant you are looking for is `NSNumberFormatterRoundDown`.

Kotlin Native does not understand Swift directly but uses Objc. For questions like this, it helps to look at the documentation in ObjC: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsnumberformatterroundingmode?language=objc